# Why codes run on machines?

Tags: compiler-construction, cpu-architecture

I can't say I fully understand how compilers work. Moreover, I know little thing about them. However, I have always wonder how is it possible for a **machine** to *understand* the code we write in a document.

I know that what we wrote it is translated to *something* (if you could also give me some details of a compilation it would be great) and then after certain operations a binary code emerges.

But how can a circuit *understand* and operate with 0s and 1s. I have some formation on computer architecture, i know how a transistor works and how an ALU works and how it is implemented. I know  how a RAM works (more or less, so any further explanation will be great too) and also the HDD.

But, i get lost when trying to imagine how a compiler engenders *magical thing* (at least for me) that fits perfectly in a tangible machine.

It amazes me. That that we take for granted every day, it is so conceptually great. The **cooperation** between an **abstract** code and a **physical** machine... amazing.

Do not worry to go deep in the machine guts if necesary in your answer, i find it really interesting and maybe you can enlighten me. The more details you give to describe this process the better.

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not the appropriate venue for this kind of question, but if you'll just read this book it explains exactly what you're asking:  [http://www.amazon.com/Code-Language-Computer-Hardware-Software/dp/0735611319](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319)

Comment: +1 for that awesome book, was just about to suggest it.  good reminder of the stuff you forgot since school, too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't understand anything. It just blindly runs whatever raw code you throw at it. How exactly it does that has changed quite a lot in the past and between different architectures.

How a Core2 or other modern x86 CPU works is far too complicated and for an answer on SO, but you can read all (well not down to the transistor level) about it in Agner Fogs [Microarchitecture](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) manual.

If you want to go deeper, you can have a look at an actual implementation over at [OpenCores.org](http://opencores.org/)

Answer (score 0):

C,C++,JAVA and similar languages are called high level languages. All the code you write in these languages eventually gets translated to another language called assembly which the processor understands. Assembly is the instruction set that the processor understands. for example on a mips process add $3, $2, $1 translates to a 32-bit or a 64-bit binary string which adds two registers in the processor.

To conclude this is what happens:

High level code -> assambly -> binary strings -> cpu

Comment: -1 for mixing up machine code with assembly language

Answer (score 0):

This question should be stated "What are good resources for understanding how is it possible for a machine to understand the code we write in a document?"  There is simply too much to explain in an SO thread.  Resources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books.) are your friend, though you should probably seek more hardware learning resources.